# Mixing ordered and unordered trees

Tags: math, tree, graph-theory

I understand that there are ordered trees in which children of all nodes do have some kind of order. And also there is unordered trees in which nodes do not have any sort of order. But I find both structures not being complementary. So is there a name for trees in which only children of some nodes have an order and  children of other nodes do not? I would have guessed 'partially ordered trees' but unfortunately thats already been taken by some different topic, namely heap trees.

In particular I am interested in trees build by mathematical expressions, e.g. "2+x^5". When transformed into a tree, I want this to be equal to the tree of "x^5 + 2", but not being equal to the tree of "2+5^x".

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for this, but I doubt there is, because such a structure is useless: If you have a node whos children are unordered, you can impose any order you want without breaking any properties of the tree, and so you get an ordered tree.

Comment: @EricPitz: I think there is some use for that. Lets say I want to transform the mathematical expression '2+x^3' into a tree. That would make 'plus' the root, followed by two children whose order don't matter, namely '2' and 'power'. And then 'power' has two more children, 'x' and '3', but these two have an order.

Comment: You can simply impose yourself an order between `2` and `^` for exemple that `^` comes first. This does not break any property of your tree, but now it is a fully ordered tree.

Comment: @EricPitz: I am sorry, I just edited my original question to point out what exactly I am after. If I impose this order to make my tree an ordered tree, it would not match another ordered tree with reversed order.

Comment: Indeed. Any rule you choose has to be shared between all trees. If you build the trees yourself this isn't a problem. If you don't build them yourself and you can't afford to reorder them to your convention, then indeed you'll need a more flexible structure.